# Как правильно обработать ошибки?

Tags: javascript

Есть такое задание:

Написать функцию `getRepeatableData`, которая принимает на вход три параметра:

- getData - функция, возвращающая данные со стороннего источника. Может генерировать ошибки (см ниже)
- key - аргумент, с которым нужно вызвать getData
- maxRequestsNumber- максимальное количество вызовов getData функции. Если этот параметр отсутствует - повторяем бесконечное количество раз.

  getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestNumber);

Функция `getRepeatableData` должна вызывать `getData` и обрабатывать ошибки по условию:

- Если вызов `getData` возвращает ошибку NotFoundError, то мы пробрасываем исключение.
- Если вызов `getData` возвращает ошибку `TemporaryError`, то мы должны делать повторный вызов `getData` функции. Кол-во таких вызовов не должно превышать значение `maxRequestsNumber`. Если кол-во повторного вызова превышает `maxRequestsNumber`, то функция getRepeatableData должна пробрасывать ошибку `AttemtsLimitExceeded`.
- Если getData выполняется без ошибок - функция должна вернуть то, что вернула `getData`. Пример:

  ```
    const getData = (key) => 'hello' + key;
    const res = getRepeatableData(getData, '1', 3); // 'hello1'
  ```

И мой вариант кода:

```
class AttemptsLimitExceeded extends Error {
  constructor(){
    super('Max attempts limit exceed');
    this.name = 'AttemptsLimitExceeded';
  }
}

class NotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor(){
    super('Not found');
    this.name = 'NotFoundError';
  }
}

class TemporaryError extends Error {
  constructor(){
    super('TemporaryError');
    this.name = 'TemporaryError';
  }
}
function getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber) {
   let output;
  try{
    output = getData(key);
  }
  catch(e){
   
    if(e instanceof NotFoundError)
      throw e;
     
    else if(e instanceof TemporaryError)
      return getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber--)
  }  
   if (){
    throw new AttemptsLimitExceeded;}// не знаю как написать условие
  return output;
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: ну заведи счетчик срабатывания getData (), и перед выбросом AttemptsLimitExceeded() проверй его, чтобы значение было не более maxRequestsNumber

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```js
class AttemptsLimitExceeded extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('Max attempts limit exceed');
    this.name = 'AttemptsLimitExceeded';
  }
}

class NotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('Not found');
    this.name = 'NotFoundError';
  }
}

class TemporaryError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('TemporaryError');
    this.name = 'TemporaryError';
  }
}

function getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber) {
  let output;

  try {
    output = getData(key);
  } catch (e) {

    if (e instanceof NotFoundError) {
      return e;
    }

    if (e instanceof TemporaryError) {
      --maxRequestsNumber;
      console.log(maxRequestsNumber);
      if (maxRequestsNumber > 0) {

        return getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber);
      } else {
        return new AttemptsLimitExceeded();
      }
    }


  }
  return output;
}


const getData = (key) => {

  if (key && key < 3) {
    return 'hello' + key;
  }

  if (!key) {
    throw new NotFoundError();
  }

  if (+key > 3) {
    throw new TemporaryError();
  }
}

res = getRepeatableData(getData, '', 3); //NotFoundError: Not found
console.log(res);

res = getRepeatableData(getData, '2', 3); //hello2
console.log(res);

res = getRepeatableData(getData, '4', 3); //Uncaught AttemptsLimitExceeded: Max attempts limit exceed
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Не сработало, проблема осталась

Answer (score 0):

`AttemptsLimitExceeded` нужно выбрасывать, когда попыток больше не осталось, а значит `maxRequestsNumber == 0`.

Таким образом достаточно добавить это условие в начало функции:

```
function getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber) {
  if (maxRequestsNumber == 0){
    throw new AttemptsLimitExceeded;
  }

  try{
    return getData(key);
  }
  catch(e){
   
    if(e instanceof TemporaryError)
      return getRepeatableData(getData, key, maxRequestsNumber-1)

    // if(e instanceof NotFoundError) // можно убрать, так как пробрасывать надо все ошибки кроме TemporaryError
      throw e;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138451/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy----).